# Improper integral comparison test

Tags: improper-integrals

Having this integral
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{3x^2+2x +1}{x^3+6x^2+x+4}$$

In order to do the comparison test at some point it gets like

$$\frac{3x^2+2x +1}{x^3+6x^2+x+4}\geq \frac{1}{4x}$$

How is $\frac{1}{4x}$ found ? It doesnt seem obvious to me.

**EDIT**
Also how is this found

$$0\leq\frac{3x +1}{\sqrt{x^5+4x^3+5x}}\leq \frac{4}{x^{3/2}}$$

Where does 4 came from here ?Minimum value ? 3x1 +1  ? Why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive $x$, the top is $\ge 3x^2$. For $x\ge 1$, the bottom is $\le x^3+6x^3+x^3+4x^3$.

**Edit:** For your added question, the range of values of $x$ is not specified. However, if $x\ge 1$, then the top is $\le 4x$. The bottom is $\ge \sqrt{x^5}$. So for $x\ge 1$, the whole thing is $\le \frac{4x}{x^{5/2}}$, which simplifies to $\frac{4}{x^{3/2}}$.

Comment: why we dont keep 3 too then ? 3/4x ? Because it has lower power ?

Comment: I kept the $3$ in $3x^2$ on top. The bottom is $\le 12x^3$. Then the $3$ cancels part of the $12$.

Comment: For your added question, you do not specify the range of values of $x$, so it is not possible to give an answer. However, for $x\ge 1$, the term $3x+1$ is $\le 4x$.

Comment: they are the same with the first. Integral from 1 to infinity

Comment: if bottom $x^5$ was like $10x^5$ would it matter too ?

Comment: The $x^{5/2}$ (see my addition to the answer) could then be replaced by $(10)^{1/2} x^{5/2}$. However, one can still accurately say that the bottom is $\ge x^{5/2}$, which is enough to show convergence.

Comment: Where can I find texts about these tricks ?

Comment: Calculus/analysis books usually spend little time on this business of knowing what to "give away." But after doing a smallish number of examples you will get reasonably good control over the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

For example, and taking into account the fact that for large values $\;x\;$ *only* the summands with the largest exponent of $\;x\;$ are important (in this sense), we get

$$\frac{3x^2+2x +1}{x^3+6x^2+x+4}\ge\frac{3x^2}{x^3+6x^3+x^3+4x^3}=\frac1{4x}$$